# Bug with LinearRecurrence and Slot/SlotSequence?

Tags: recursion, pure-function, slot

The code below runs without any error:

```
LinearRecurrence[{##}, {1}, 5]
```

Each term is the previous term squared, times the index of the previous term.

If the `##` is substituted with `##2` or `##3`, the code returns an array of `1`s. `##4` or higher `SlotSequence`s throw errors.

I'm sure this is a bug, but I don't understand why this is happening; `Trace` doesn't seem to reveal anything. Why does the above code behave that way?

Comment: Also, `LinearRecurrence[{#}, {1}, 5]` outputs the same thing as `Factorial`.

Comment: Using a symbolic starting value might be more informative: `LinearRecurrence[{##2}, {C[1]}, 5]`.

Comment: Is this undocumented functionality? I don't see anything in the function docs for `LinearRecurrence`, and I can't think of any other documented functions where you use `Slot` or `SlotSequence` outside of `Function`.

Comment: Funnily enough, `DifferenceRoot[Function[{a, n}, {a[n + 1] == ## a[n], a[1] == 1}]][
 Range[5]]` and `LinearRecurrence[{##}, {1}, 5]` give the same results. This is very peculiar indeed.